# How to pass exception information to an error page?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to pass error information back from an error on a Spring Webflow 2 page through an AbstractFlowHandler.    The relevant code looks like this:

```
@Override
public String handleException(FlowException e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (e instanceof NoSuchFlowExecutionException) {
        return DEFAULT_URL;
    } else {
        logger.warn(String.format("Flow threw exception %1$s", e.getMessage()), e);
        return ERROR_URL;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  *The "normal" result of simply returning back to the calling routine at this point is always a 302 REDIRECT, so the "request" and "response" objects attached to this call are lost, and fresh objects are created when the redirect is executed.   LeandreM's comment below (using forward()) gives a workaround, but it would be nice if there was some way around that redirect INSIDE the normal processing path.  However, I have not been able to find one.*

What I would like to do is pass the exception object "e" along to the error page, so that I can print some information about it.  But I can't figure out the "proper" way to do this - do I attach it to the request object, the response object, or do it some other way?

Comment: Try out `request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.jsp.JspException",e)` `request.getRequestDispatcher(errorPageURL).forward(request,   
                   response);`

Comment: This worked, although I'm concerned about jumping out of the natural flow with the forward() call.  However, I'm at the point where I need results, so I'm going to roll with it.   Thanks!